# Unknown Heap Growth

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

Is there anyone out there who can help me or explain more ?

I minimize my codes to use a button to alloc and add UIPickerView to self.view. By pressing the same button, the UIPickerView is removed from self.view and released.

On each removing of UIPickerView, I took a HeapShot with Instrutments. I found that sometimes, there are 0 bytes change, 4xx bytes, ... 2K bytes and 4K bytes in Heap Growth. There is no Leakage (RED BAR).

Actually, my concern is that when the Heap usage is growing larger and larger. Finally, my application would crash and it is the case now. When I do 25 times of taking photo and submit to my server, the Heap grows to 1x MB (There is no obvious Leakage by checking with Instructments.

Any more suggestion ?

Here are my codes for the button. It seems that my allocation and release are corret

```
- (void) nextButtonClicked {
    if (!pickerShown) {
        UIPickerView *pickervTemp = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 200.0, 320.0, 216.0)];
        self.locationPicker = pickervTemp;
        [pickervTemp release];
        [_locationPicker setDelegate:self];
        [_locationPicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:_locationPicker];
        pickerShown = YES;
    } else {
        pickerShown = NO;
        [_locationPicker removeFromSuperview];
        [_locationPicker release];
        _locationPicker = nil;
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIPickerView` has a personality. Much like `UIWebView` you don't want to create the things too often even if you are throwing them away afterwards. Its not a leak but your heap will rise.

The solution to your problem might be to only create the picker once and keep a hold of it for re-use only discarding it when you dismantle the parent view controller.

Comment: Thanks. That's my thought too. It seems that when a UI object is kept allocating and release, even I saw that the corresponding dealloc of the object is called and executed, the Heap still grows up.